# angular 6, RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

In my app I am trying to print an example of the current date in the current local by-

```js
console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB') );
```

I tried this as well-

```js
console.log( new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }) );
```

but for some reason I am getting this error-
RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: undefined

I do not know why, this is a valid time zone. I read  few posts but didn't understand how to make it work.

Comment: It's working for me. new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
 // Prints "26 November 2018"

Comment: Converting your code to runnable snippets shows the code does not exhibit the behaviour described. So I'm voting to close as off topic, your error is elsewhere.

Comment: I am getting this- {
  "message": "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time zone specified: undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 33
}

Comment: Maybe it's related to my version in Chrome?